# Bukkit/Spigot. When I enter command, it just returns the command

Tags: java, bukkit

When I use the command /heal in game, it returns with /heal in game chat. I don't understand why this is happening at all.
Here is my code (all in one class):

```
public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, Strings [] args) {

    Player player = (Player) sender;

    if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("heal")) {
        if (sender.hasPermission("city.heal")) {
            player.setHealth(20);
            player.setFoodLevel(20);
            sender.sendMessage("§fYou have been §bhealed §fand §bsated§f.");
            return true;
        }

        if (!sender.hasPermission("city.heal")) {
            sender.sendMessage("§cNo permission.");
            return true;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

And here is my plugin.yml:

```
main: me.rarfiles.code.Code
name: Test
author: rarfiles
version: 1.0

commands:
  heal:
    usage: /<command>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you register your CommandExecutor in the onEnable method.
By doing `getCommand("heal").setExecutor(Instance of CommandExecutor);`

You also need to make sure you check if the sender is an player by doing
`if(sender instanceof Player)`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you imported **org.bukkit.Command** and not **com.mojang.brigadier.Command**

Hope this helped